# iOS app freezes on blank screen while connecting debugger after launching on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

After deploying the app to my device using Xcode 12.2 the app launches and hangs on a blank screen (not the launch screen). The debugger shows nothing but pausing a breakpoint seems to suggest it's connecting the debugger. There is no issue launching and connecting the debugger in the Simulator. Deleting derived data, restarting the device, etc doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

**Delete the Device Support files** in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`, reconnect your device, and deploy!